# How to scroll element with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

how to scroll a certain page element, not the page itself, but the element, there is a list that is updated dynamically and to get all its elements I need to scroll it to the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You can use*

```
org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = driver.find_element_by_id("my-id")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

**OR**

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

If you wan to scroll to the end of the page then the  easiest way is to select a label and then send:

```
label.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
```

**OR**

```
label.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

Hope this answer

Comment: Only yesterday the method with label selection and send_keys worked for me, today the same code gives an error: Message: element not interactable. I do not understand what the problem is

Comment: Try the above way i mentioned in the answer by using some `waits` i hope this will resolve your issue, in case you still get the issue then add the `code` in the question